# Implementing exists for list in F#

Tags: list, f#, exists

I am new to programming in functional languages. I am attempting to implement the F# exist for list.

`let rec exist f list = 
   match list with 
   |[] -> None 
   | h::t -> if f h then true 
             else exist f t`

The error shows up when compiling the file was:
"This expression was expected to have type 'a option but here has type bool" 
and idk how exactly I should fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't clear ***at all***. Please provide the **full error and issue**.

Comment: Both cases need to return the same type - your first clause for the empty list returns `None` (an `Option<'t>`) while the one for non-empty lists returns `bool`. You should change the first clause to return a `bool`.

Comment: oh thank you so much. I figured it out now.

Comment: @Lee - post this as an answer so that it can be accepted & up-voted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of the function is conflicting. When matching with `[]`, your code gives None, which is an option type. When matching with `h::t`, however, it gives either a boolean or calls recursion.

Minimally invasive correction, assuming bool return type:

```
let rec exist f list =
    match list with
    | [] -> false
    | h::t -> if f h then true else exist f t
```

More invasive correction, assuming bool return type

```
let rec exist f = function
    | [] -> false
    | h::t -> f h || exist f t
```

Note that the short-circuiting operator `||` does not call the recursion if the left side returns true.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating my comment as an answer:

Both cases of your `match` expression need to return the same type. The first clause for the empty list returns `None` which has type `'a Option`. In contract, the one for non-empty lists returns bool. You should change the first clause to return a `bool`.